# My ussername checker keeps saying all names are available, despite if/else test

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, logic

I'm attempting to make a simple, small, practice program for checking usernames using if-elif-else statements.

```
current_users = ['Enrique', 'Jose', 'Pablo', 'John', 'Jake']
new_users = ['Mike', 'Tom', 'Bowser', 'John', 'Howard', 'Ben']

'''for user in current_users:
        user = user.lower()
        print(user)

   for user in new_users:
        user = user.lower()
        print(user)
'''


for user in new_users:
    if user.lower() == current_users:
        print(f"{user}: That username is taken.")
    else:
        print(f"{user}: That username is available.")
```

I expect for it to print the message "That username is taken" for a username that's on both the new_user list and the current_user list, but instead, they all evaluate the True when I run them in the Sublime text editor.

I know it's a logic error because no actual error message is given, but I can't quite see it yet.

I've tried inverting the loop by starting with checking if a username from the new_users list is NOT from the current_users list.

As you can see, I've tried changing all of the usernames to lowercase to see if it would help, but it doesn't.

Comment: It can't give your expected outcome because you are _comparing equality to a list object_. Swap `==` to `in`. You want to test for membership _within_ a collection, not compare it to the whole collection

Comment: `current_users` is a list; it's never equal to a single name.

Answer (score 1):

When you look for values in a list use "in" operator.

```
    current_users = ['Enrique', 'Jose', 'Pablo', 'John', 'Jake']
    new_users = ['Mike', 'Tom', 'Bowser', 'John', 'Howard', 'Ben']


    for user in new_users:
        if user in current_users:
            print(f"{user}: That username is taken.")
        else:
            print(f"{user}: That username is available.")
```

Comment: Rookie mistake on my behalf. Thank you, Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you were comparing a string to a list of strings `user.lower() = current_user`.

Moreover, you are comparing `user.lower()` to `user`.

example means `"Jhon".lower() == "Jhon"` will give you `False`

TRY THIS:

create a temporary list of `current_user` with all the name in lower case
then check if it already has taken or available.

```
current_users = ['Enrique', 'Jose', 'Pablo', 'John', 'Jake']
new_users = ['Mike', 'Tom', 'Bowser', 'John', 'Howard', 'Ben']

t_current_user = [x.lower() for x in current_users]

for user in new_users:
    if user.lower() in t_current_user:
        print(f"{user}: That username is taken.")
    else:
        print(f"{user}: That username is available.")
```